# Issue while creating bar graph and having legend in the right side

Tags: html, css

I got an requirement to create a horizontal bar graph with legend in right side.

Attached the image of graph..

[image: Graph image]

the issue I am facing is when one of the bar is reaching 100% of parent div then the legend coming to next line ( 1st bar of my image).

I tried to create bar using div and legend using span. The graph is dynamically generated from a List. So any css needs to be used, needs to be applied for all the element.

here is my code snippet..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> <html>
     <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
       <title>Floating</title>
    <style>
  .border
  {
   border-left:1px solid black;
   border-bottom:1px solid black;
   height:100px;
   width:20%;
   overflow:visible;
  }
  .bar{
   border:1px solid black;
   background-color:red;
   height:20px;
   display:inline-block;
  }
  .legend{
  display:inline-block;
  }
  </style>
     </head>
     <body>
  <div class="border">
  <br />
   <!-- dynamically assigning the width of div in real application-->
   <div type="text" class="bar" style="width:100%"></div>
   <span class="legend">100%</span>
  <br /> 
   <!-- dynamically assigning the width of div in real application-->
   <div class="bar" style="width:80%"></div>
   <span class="legend">80%</span>
  </div>
  </body>
   </html>
```

Note : I have used two divs and spans for sample purpose only. In real application, I am using MVC and running a for loop to generate the bar and legend..

Any help on if the bar reached 100% how can I have my legend in the right side? Thanks a lot in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `white-space: nowrap` to your `.border` element to prevent the legend text from wrapping to the next line.

**Live Demo:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> <html>
     <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
       <title>Floating</title>
    <style>
  .border
  {
   border-left:1px solid black;
   border-bottom:1px solid black;
   height:100px;
   width:20%;
   overflow:visible;
            white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .bar{
   border:1px solid black;
   background-color:red;
   height:20px;
   display:inline-block;
  }
  .legend{
  display:inline-block;
  }
  </style>
     </head>
     <body>
  <div class="border">
  <br />
   <!-- dynamically assigning the width of div in real application-->
   <div type="text" class="bar" style="width:100%"></div>
   <span class="legend">100%</span>
  <br /> 
   <!-- dynamically assigning the width of div in real application-->
   <div class="bar" style="width:80%"></div>
   <span class="legend">80%</span>
  </div>
  </body>
   </html>
```